# Navbar won't update active li on first click

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, html-lists

When I click on my navbar the second time, the clicked link changes to active but not on the first click.
Any ideas why? It is working only after the second click, but does not work in this code snippet... 
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated....!!!!
Hi,
When I click on my navbar the second time, the clicked link changes to active but not on the first click.
Any ideas why? It is working only after the second click, but does not work in this code snippet... 
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated....!!!!
Hi,
When I click on my navbar the second time, the clicked link changes to active but not on the first click.
Any ideas why? It is working only after the second click, but does not work in this code snippet... 
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated....!!!!

```js
function somethingSector() {
  doUpdateNavSector();
}

function doUpdateNavSector() {
  $(".start").addClass("active");
  $(".navTopNavSector a").click(function () {
    $(".navTopNavSector a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
}
```

```css
.navTopNavSector {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     line-height: 2;
     overflow: visible;
     padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
}
 .navTopNavSector li{
     width:auto;
     float:left;
     padding:0;
     list-style-type: none;
     position:relative;
}
 .navTopNavSector li a{
     font-family: "Arial";
     display: inline-block;
     color: #bdb6ae;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 0px 25px 0px 0px;
     text-decoration: none;
     transition: 0.3s;
     font-weight: 700;
     font-size: 18px;
}
/* Change color on hover */
 .navTopNavSector a:hover {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #00ff00;
     text-decoration: none;
}
/* Active/current link */
 .navTopNavSector a.active {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #ff00ff;
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navigation">
                <ul class="navTopNavSector">
                    <li><a href="#/" onclick="somethingSector()" class="active">ALL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/" onclick="somethingSector()">ARB</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/" onclick="somethingSector()">ARC</a></li>
                </ul>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
function doUpdateNavSector() {
  $(".start").addClass("active");
  $(".navTopNavSector a").click(function () {
    $(".navTopNavSector a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need this attribute `onclick='somethingSector()'` , since you are attaching event `click` using jQuery, here is a snippet with a fix, the issue is you always execute

```
$('.start').addClass('active');
```

and this sets the first element to be selected on each click you do on other `<a>`tags, also the click event reattaches the click event again on all elements, you only need to execute this once, note that I removed the functions from the code too

---

**Update**: I used native Javascript code, and used `.classList.add()` and `.classList.remove()` to toggle the class attribute, also kept the `onclick` event attribute:

```js
function somethingSector(el) {
  document.querySelector('.navTopNavSector .active').classList.remove("active");
  el.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.navTopNavSector {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     line-height: 2;
     overflow: visible;
     padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
}
 .navTopNavSector li{
     width:auto;
     float:left;
     padding:0;
     list-style-type: none;
     position:relative;
}
 .navTopNavSector li a{
     font-family: "Arial";
     display: inline-block;
     color: #bdb6ae;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 0px 25px 0px 0px;
     text-decoration: none;
     transition: 0.3s;
     font-weight: 700;
     font-size: 18px;
}
/* Change color on hover */
 .navTopNavSector a:hover {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #00ff00;
     text-decoration: none;
}
/* Active/current link */
 .navTopNavSector a.active {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #ff00ff;
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navigation">
                <ul class="navTopNavSector">
                    <li><a href="#/" onclick="somethingSector(this)" class="active">ALL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/" onclick="somethingSector(this)">ARB</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/" onclick="somethingSector(this)">ARC</a></li>
                </ul>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
The thing is, I do need the "onclick='doSomethingHere()".

I am actually calling external html pages to be displayed on the landing page using All.style.display = block and "none.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?
I was so close... until I hit this wall...
;-(

Comment: Ok let me check this again.

Comment: @Ekato, I updated my answer, please check it, also note that I did it using native javascript.

Comment: You are FANTASTIC!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Thank you so MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Glad to help :) please consider [accepting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find my answer useful :)